# Calling variables between different classes through methods

Tags: java, arrays, variables

I'm doing an assignment for my computer science class.

I've done quite a bit of the assignment, but I'm having a little bit of trouble pulling the individual variables from the classes. We are just getting into classes and objects and this is our first assignment regarding them so I don't completely understand all of it. So far I've been able to print out the teams, but I haven't been able to pull the individual wins, losses, OTL and OTW so that I can compute whether or not each individual team is a winning team.

What I have done so far is create a class called winningRecord and getPoints, which returns a boolean deciding whether it's a winning team or not. (The formula for a winning team is if the points are > Games Played * 1.5 (as that is an even record).

I don't know how to pull the stats, as it has to be written in the HockeyTeam class. I have set it up so that the constructor sets the variables publicly so that the can be accessed, but as far as accessing them, I'm stumped.

As far as storing them once I am able to access them, would I just make a parallel method that has the points for each team, with just one digit assigned to each bin?

Here is all of the code, thanks for looking.

```
public class A1Q2fixed {
    public static void main(String[] parms) { // main method
        processHockeyTeams();
    }

    /*****************************/

    public static void processHockeyTeams() { // processing method
        boolean[] winningRecord;
        HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeams;

        hockeyTeams = createTeams();
        printTeams(hockeyTeams);
        System.out.print("*********************\n");
        printWinningTeams();
        winningRecord = HockeyTeam.winningRecord(hockeyTeams);
        // printWinningTeams(hockeyTeams); 
    }

    /*********************************/

    public static void printTeams(HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeams) {
        for (int i = 0; i < hockeyTeams.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(hockeyTeams[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void printWinningTeams() {

    }

    public static HockeyTeam[] createTeams() {
        HockeyTeam[] teams;
        HockeyTeam team;
        int count;

        teams = new HockeyTeam[HockeyTeams.getNumberTeams()];
        team = HockeyTeams.getTeam();
        for (count = 0; (count < teams.length) && (team != null); count++) {
            teams[count] = team;
            team = HockeyTeams.getTeam();
        }
        return teams;
    }
}

/* hockey team class *******/

class HockeyTeam {
    public String name;
    public int wins;
    public int otw;
    public int otl;
    public int losses;

    public HockeyTeam(String name, int wins, int otw, int otl, int losses) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.otw = otw;
        this.otl = otl;
        this.losses = losses;
    }

    public String toString() {
        System.out.println(name);

        return " W:" + wins + " OTW:" + otw + " OTL:" + otl + " L:" + losses;
    }

    public static boolean[] winningRecord(HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeam) {
        boolean array[] = new boolean[hockeyTeam.length];

        String name;
        int wins;
        int otw;
        int otl;
        int losses;

        for (int i = 0; i < hockeyTeam.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(HockeyTeam.name);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int getPoints() {
        int points = 0;
        return points;
    }
}

/* hockey teams class *******************/
class HockeyTeams {
    private static int count = 0;

    private static HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeams = {
            new HockeyTeam("Canada", 5, 3, 0, 0),
            new HockeyTeam("Russia", 5, 1, 1, 2),
            new HockeyTeam("Finland", 3, 2, 1, 3),
            new HockeyTeam("Sweden", 4, 1, 1, 4),
            new HockeyTeam("USA", 1, 2, 2, 3), };

    public static int getNumberTeams() {
        return hockeyTeams.length;
    }

    public static HockeyTeam getTeam() {
        HockeyTeam hockeyTeam;

        hockeyTeam = null;
        if (count < hockeyTeams.length) {
            hockeyTeam = hockeyTeams[count];
            count++;
        }
        return hockeyTeam;
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: I really dont understand what variable you want to access. You have two classes named `HockeyTeam` and `HockeyTeams` and in none of them I see no variable named `stat`

Comment: That's the best formatted code I've ever seen from a student... (Oops, I mean... nice work, Perception!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I was only able to understand only a part of your question,from what I understood it seems you are not able to access individual wins, losses, OTL and OTW. I hope this answers your question if not please clarify a bit

1. To access OTL,OTW have a loop as below:

   ```
   public class A1Q2fixed

   { 
    public static void main(String[] parms) // main method
    {
     processHockeyTeams(); 
    } 
    /*****************************/

    public static void processHockeyTeams()  // processing method
    {

     boolean[] winningRecord;

     HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeams;



     hockeyTeams = createTeams(); 

     printTeams(hockeyTeams);

     System.out.print("*********************\n");

     printWinningTeams();

       winningRecord = HockeyTeam.winningRecord(hockeyTeams);

       for(HockeyTeam h:hockeyTeams)
       {
           System.out.println(h.losses);//To access and print losses

                System.out.println(h.otw);//To access and print otw

                System.out.println(h.otl);//To access and print otl

       }


     // printWinningTeams(hockeyTeams); 
    } 

    /*********************************/

    public static void printTeams(HockeyTeam[] hockeyTeams)

    {

      for (int i = 0; i < hockeyTeams.length; i++)

      {

        System.out.println(hockeyTeams[i]);

      }

    }

    public static void printWinningTeams()

    {

    }

    public static HockeyTeam[] createTeams() 
    { 
     HockeyTeam[] teams; 

     HockeyTeam team; 

     int count; 

     teams = new HockeyTeam[HockeyTeams.getNumberTeams()]; 

     team = HockeyTeams.getTeam(); 

     for (count=0; (count<teams.length) && (team!=null); count++) 
     { 

      teams[count] = team; 

      team = HockeyTeams.getTeam(); 

     } 

     return teams; 

    } 

   }
   ```
2. Also declare name as Static in  HockeyTeam